# How do I calculate market share in Tableau while maintaining a fixed base?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I am looking for a way to calculate market share for a given country but need the base to remain constant. It's my understanding that I cannot utilize the table calculation for "% of total" because obviously it will always be 100%.

Here is the scenario in detail:

I'm looking to add the market share % detail to my dashboard. I have 36 countries as well as seven groups of countries I'd like the user to be able to select. There is a map as well as a drop-down parameter to select these countries/groups. The goal is to have one percentage displayed on the dashboard based on the user's selection. The base will always be the 36 country total sales.

Am I overlooking something obvious? Has anyone had a similar dilemma?

Comment: Well, assuming you have a table with the total market for each country, it shouldn't be hard to do something like SUM(Sales)/MAX(Market), or something like that. Tell us what do you have in terms of database, and I can give a more specific approach

Comment: Unfortunately I have one static worksheet that my dashboard is populating from, so the data isn't normalized. My fields are as follows:

- Year
- Region
- Country
- Segment
- Brand
- Unit Sales

I'm really trying to avoid restructuring the data as much as possible because this is a preliminary submission and once the deliverable (format, info, etc) is approved by the client, we'll be given access to connect to their cube.

Comment: Well, as long as you link the 2 tables on Country, you can still use SUM(Sales) / SUM([table2].[Unit Sales]), and put it in the worksheet by Country/Region

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and created a table for Total Market Sales and linked the two sheets by Country. Next I created a calculated field Country Market Share: 

sum([Country Sales]) / sum([Total Market Sales])

When I View Data, the field is calculating correctly on a model by model basis but when I drop it into the worksheet, it is inaccurate.

Comment: Create a twbx that reproduces the problem (can be with dummy data, as long as it reproduces the same problem) and share with us. Easier to assess looking at what's happening.

Comment: Not quite sure how to attach  the twbx file.

Comment: use some upload site and share the link

Comment: I've actually figured out a workaround for this first submission. It won't work when I use the cube but on the static worksheet, its sufficient. By creating a column in the data for Global Sales and ensuring the column contains the same value throughout, I created a calculated field:

sum([Units Sold]) / attr([2013 Global Sales])

which returns the market share of the country that is selected in the parameter.

Thanks for your help on this!